# Extract link from td href element with Java

Tags: java, html, velocity

I have this HTML code:

```
<table id="myTable">
    <tr class="header">
        <th> FLIGHT NUMBER </th>
        <th> AIRLINE </th>
        <th> FROM AIRPORT </th>
        <th> TO AIRPORT </th>
        <th> FLIGHT DATE </th>
        <th> DEPARTURE TIME </th>
        <th> ARRIVING TIME </th>
        <th> BOOK </th>
    </tr>
    #foreach ($flight in $flights)
        <tr>
            <td>$flight.flightNumber</td>
            <td>$flight.airline</td>
            <td>$flight.fromAirportName</td>
            <td>$flight.toAirportName</td>
            <td>$flight.flightDate</td>
            <td>$flight.departureTime</td>
            <td>$flight.arrivingTime</td>
            <td class="topic"><a href="/booking/${flight.flightNumber}">
                <p style="text-align:center">BOOK</p></a></td>
        </tr>
    #end
</table>
```

I want to extract `flight.flightNumber` from  `<td class="topic"><a href="/booking/${flight.flightNumber}">` using Java.
I tried with `Element` but don't know exactly how it works.

Comment: Show your work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Rejex to find $flight.flightNumber. The code would be like this:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<tr>\\s*<td>([^<]+)<\\/td>");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(command);
```

Then every time you call matcher.find(), it will find the next flight number and returns false if there is no more. After calling that, you can get that number using matcher.group(1).